# What has been the reason for downvote?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

I can't find any possible explanation for my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/830609/evaluate-the-integrals-int-sinx-cot2x-dx-and-int-cosx-cot2x/1137691#1137691). The thing is not that I am concerned about the decrease of my reputation, but to me the answer looks perfect and so I can't find any reason for downvoting. Can the meta users (it will be good if the original downvoter comments here) help me to understand what is it that has gone wrong with my answer so that I mayn't repeat the same mistake again?

Comment: @downvoter probably don't want to share the reason, right?

Comment: You're not the first one to ask this. See e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/18937/43351). -1 for not searching meta before posting.

Comment: @Lord_Farin: I have immediately asked the reason. Probably you should look in the link once more. Note that this user also downvoted other users including **lab** at the same time.

Comment: As usual, the reason is that [Tim Post lost his keys](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/214632).

Comment: It seems (though I did not look carefully) that this question was answered anew many months after it was originally asked and answered. This is unusual, at least for this type of question and answer, and might have annoyed somebody. (I do not wish to argue if this is reasonable or not; it is merely a speculation on the actual motivation.)

Comment: That, and perhaps the nontrivial (and not mentioned) overlap with already posted answers.

Comment: Downvotes are random. My favorite arose when [Joe Taxpayer's dog jumped him.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619852/find-five-consecutive-odd-integers-such-that-their-sum-is-55/619991#comment1309759_619991)

Answer (score -10, accepted):

I didn't downvote your answer, rather I upvoted to counter that downvote because I found your answer useful and I think it should have a net positive score. The thing is that according to the *current* network-wide policy a user is not obliged to explain the reason of his/her vote. So the hard truth is that you have to get used to it. I can speculate many reasons behind that downvote. Why waste time in speculations!? Forget it, and keep movin'.

Now, since the net score of your answer is positive, you should take it as that nothing is wrong with your answer and it is ok for the site and useful to some people. Nowadays I am seeing that zero research effort question get deleted anyway, so it is always dangerous to answer that kind of questions.

Hope this helps.

P.S: I was trying to write this as a comment but it got lengthy so added it as an answer. I know that my answer doesn't answer your specific question that why did you get downvote. The thing is people vote differently as per their wish. E.g. I never downvote, and some users never upvote. So it would be difficult to speculate the exact reason.

Comment: "I never downvote" except for the 35 times you did?

Comment: Some users [argue strongly against](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2234/242) "pity upvotes"

Comment: @quid I do not remember when I casted those.

Comment: @quid I searched in my profile and I found that I've downvoted 18 times not 35 times. IIRC I downvoted some spam posts only. Edit: link: http://math.stackexchange.com/users/103816/user31782?tab=votes

Comment: @user31782 The link you posted is only visible to you, not to other users. In your profile http://math.stackexchange.com/users/103816/user31782 you can see (at the moment): 881 votes cast, 846 up, 35 down. So I suppose this is where quid took that number from.

Comment: @MartinSleziak It gives me 723-total votes, 695-upvotes and 18 downvotes. By th eway if you can't see that link then how do you know how many votes have I casted? Are you using some SE script. Edit: I've made the total votes 724 recently to verify things.

Comment: @user31782 I'll try to explain once again. You posted the following link: http://math.stackexchange.com/users/103816/user31782?tab=votes When I try to use it, I get "Page Not Found". If you want you can try to do the same with this link: http://math.stackexchange.com/users/8297/martin-sleziak?tab=votes When I am logged in, I can see there my voting history. But I expect that it is not shown to you. I have posted another link: http://math.stackexchange.com/users/103816/user31782 That is link to your profile page, which is publicly visible. I read there the numbers of votes I wrote above.

Comment: And [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146668/different-value-of-votes-in-profile-page-summary-tab-vs-votes-tab) is the explanation why the number of votes on votes tab and summary tab differ.

Comment: I saw it were @MartinSleziak said: on your user page, towards the end, at the right: "votes cast" that gives a breakdown up/down and q/a and some info on recent votes. It is expected there is a difference there, as these are all the votes cast while the tab you give will only lis those on not deleted posts (IIRC). [I see you got a link on that.] Either way 18 would still not be never. In that list you could in fact check what you voted on. So, there are 18 of your dv "spam" posts that did not even get deleted. (I have a better rate of dv-posts getting eventually deleted, while I do not try.)

Comment: @quid Perhaps someone else used my id on my PC. I myself never downvote.

Comment: Spam flags carry an automatic downvote. (See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work/58035#58035).) Maybe you have flagged some such posts and they might result in a downvote without you knowing about it. (But I guess we have wildly digressed from the points you were trying to make in your post.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Automatic downvotes are attributed to Community bot, not to the user casting spam flag.

Comment: Curiously enough, the original downvoter have removed his/her downvote. However, I think that it should be made mandatory for the downvoters (and perhaps upvoters also to some extent) to give precise reasons for downvoting. This may look like a really annoying constraint but I think that it probably is the most logical way to prevent this kind of issues.

Comment: @user170039 Re: *I think that it should be made mandatory for the downvoters.* If you mean leaving comment, that was discussed on this meta several times. For example this post and other posts linked from/to it: [Downvoting for no stated reason is abusive](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3153/downvoting-for-no-stated-reason-is-abusive). But maybe you have something else in mind. (Like some dialogue, which opens when voting and user has to fill in the reason. And this would be stored somewhere and reasons for votes would be accessible to users.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Actually I had faced similar issues earlier and the community didn't provide me any precise explanation. For example see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc-volume-10-2012-12-2014/17446#17446). It makes me confused when someone downvotes without giving any reason. Anyway, thanks for the link.

Comment: @user170039 If you meant that your post on meta was downvoted, you should keep in mind that [voting is different on meta](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta). Downvotes on meta generally indicate disagreement with the position stated in the post.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: No. I didn't mean that my post on meta was downvoted. I mean that no **precise** explanation was given.